# Controller not loading ocLazyLoad

Tags: angularjs, oclazyload

I have newly included the lazyload library.

```
var app = angular.module(subdomain, ['ngRoute','ngResource','ngCookies','ngSanitize','angular-md5','mm.foundation','chieffancypants.loadingBar', 'ngAnimate','ui-notification','infinite-scroll','oc.lazyLoad']);
```

I have loaded the controller in routes page:

```
 $routeProvider
     .when('/',
     {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
        access: { requiredLogin: true },
        resolve: {
            lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name: 'app',
                    files: ['dist/home.min.js']
                }]);
            }]
        },
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
```

and my controller file has:

```
app.controller("homeController",[....])
```

I am getting home controller not defined error. If I change the app to angular.module in the controller its working but that's not what I want. Is there any solution for this so I can use app variable?

Comment: How do you have your modules structured?

Comment: ah, ok...now I understand. Good luck!

Comment: do u know the solution ? I am new to angular!!

Comment: I am loading in order modules routes filters directives and services

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're having the same issue as this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44414548/1040731

You should reference your controller through the module `angular.module('myapp').controller('homeController',...)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'insertBefore' property :
set id for

```
<script id='tag-id' src='app.module.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

then :

```
$routeProvider
     .when('/',
     {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
        access: { requiredLogin: true },            
        resolve: {
            lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name: 'app',
                    insertBefore: '#tag-id',
                    files: ['dist/home.min.js']
                }]);
            }]
        },
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
```